# Setting a Forms Authentication cookie from a .NET client application

Tags: .net, forms, forms-authentication

We currently have a .NET 2.0 web app that uses forms authentication via cookies.  Associated with this web app is an old VB6 client application that has its own login system.

Currently, the users have to login to the VB6 app, and then when they click on a link, need to authenticate themselves again with the .NET forms authentication system.

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a client side .NET application, give it the username and password, and set the forms authentication cookie (without the browser being opened).

Is that possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Application Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb547119.aspx). The were designed to accomplish this specifically.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted.  Thanks for the pointer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.aspx